# jQuery UI DatePicker - only show 3 days of entire year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm wondering if it's possible to show only 3 days a year in the datepicker?

This is what I got so far:

JS:

```
 var availableDates = ["28-12-2017","29-12-2017","30-12-2017"];

 function available(date) {
   dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + 
   date.getFullYear();
   if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) !== -1) {
     return [true, "","Available"];
   } else {
     return [false,"","unAvailable"];
   }
 }

 $('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
```

css:

```
.ui-datepicker-unselectable {display: none;}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ciel0s/szYYY/49/)

Comment: If your are satisfied with the answer then please mark this solutions.

Comment: is there a way to hide the unused days ?

Comment: u can hide based on weekends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to remove the hardcoded date and make the code more generic:

**JS:**

```
 var availableDates = ["28-12-2017", "29-12-2017", "30-12-2017"];

 function available(date) {
   dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
   if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) !== -1) {
     return [true, "", "Available"];
   } else {
     return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
   }
 }

 $('#date').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: available,
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
   minDate: availableDates[0],
   maxDate: availableDates[2]
 });
```

**No CSS required.**

Displaying the full month with disabled dates gives clarity to the user rather than hiding the dates.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/szYYY/52/

Answer (score 2):

Dear you forgot **defaultDate**, please try this:

```
  var availableDates = ["28-12-2017","29-12-2017","30-12-2017"];

  function available(date) {
   dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) !== -1) {
      return [true, "","Available"];
    } else {
      return [false,"","unAvailable"];
    }
  }

  $('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available, defaultDate: "12/28/2017" });
```

Please use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szYYY/50/